# How to reinit required module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have custom module (simple examples):

```
const myModule = function() {
    'hash': localStorage.getItem('hash')
}

export default myModule;
```

And I require this module in two other modules:

one.js:

```
import myModule from './myModule';

somethingAction(myModule);
```

two.js:

```
import myModule from './myModule';

otherAction(myModule);
```

The problem is that when a user enters the page, he must first enter the value "hash", so if he opens application, then my module is initialized with hash === null.

If he entered value hash, then he can use others modules, but modules are binded with hash === null.

If I refresh the page, then everything is working good, so issue is with reinit module after user enters hash.

How is the best way for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you are trying to retrieve the object from the module, then the solution is simple.

You need to call the function inside the module instead of passing it.

Here the Ex.

myModule.js

```
const getHash = () => {
 return { hash: localStorage.getItem("hash") };
};
export default getHash;
```

one.js

```
import getHash from '../myModule.js';
somethingAction(getHash());
```

two.js

```
import getHash from '../myModule.js';
otherAction(getHash());
```

When you are calling the function it will return the current hash value from the `LocalStorage` so no need to refresh the page.

Hope it will help you.

**Edited**

If the hash token is from API, you can get and update it once. Before calling the getHash.

like below.

```
fetch('http://www.exmaple.com/hascode')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => localStorage.setItem('hash', res.token)) //consider the response like this {token: 'some_token'}
```

Then you can call `getHash` from `myModule`. Even though you have imported it already.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have other issue. Function getHash is called two times. In this example this is not problem, but what if I have in this function connection to external service by API?

Comment: You mean, getting the hash token from API instead `LocalStorage`? @zili

Comment: Yes, for example yes. Second example: For myModule I set listeners, so if I require two times, then listeners are called two times.